# Behavior of std::packaged_task and std::function

Tags: multithreading, c++11, std-function, packaged-task

My question is from [this](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h) implementation of a ThreadPool class in C++11. Following is relevant parts from the code:

1. whenever `enqueue` is called on the threadPool object, it binds the passed function with all passed arguments, to create a `shared_ptr` of `std::packaged_task`:

```
    auto task = std::make_shared< std::packaged_task<return_type()> >(
        std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    );
```

2. extracts the `future` from this `std::packaged_task`to return to the caller and stores this `task` in a  `std::queue<std::function<void()>> tasks;`.
3. In the constructor, it waits for the task in queue, and if it finds one, it executes the task:

```
    for(size_t i = 0;i<threads;++i)
        workers.emplace_back(
            [this]
            {
                for(;;)
                {
                    std::function<void()> task;
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
                        this->condition.wait(lock,[this]{ return !this->tasks.empty(); });
                        task = std::move(this->tasks.front());
                        this->tasks.pop();
                    }
                    task();
                }
            }
        );
```

Now, based on this, following is my questions:

1. If `std::packaged_task` was stored in a `std::queue<std::function<void()>>`, then it just becomes a `std::function` object, right? then how does it still write to the shared state of `std::future` extracted earlier?
2. If stored `std::packaged_task` was not just a `std::function` object but still a `std::packaged_task`then when a `std::thread` executes `task()` through a lambda (code inside constructor), then why doesn't it run on another thread? as `std::packaged_task` are supposed to run on another thread, right?

As my questions suggest, I am unable to understand the conversion of `std::packaged_task` into `std::function` and the capability of `std::function` to write to the shared state of `std::future`. Whenever I tested this code with n threads, the maximum number of thread ids I could get was n but never more than n. [Here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c3755d63175d7b5) is the complete code (including that of `ThreadPool` and it also includes a main function which counts the number of threads created).

Comment: 1. It doesn't *become* `std::function` - it gets wrapped in a `std::function` object. `std::function` can wrap any callable (an object to which a function call operator can be applied). When `std::function` is called, it applies that operator to the object it wraps.

Comment: 2. I don't understand this question. Why doesn't *what* run on another thread? What makes you believe it doesn't? What problem do you believe exists in the code? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: The worker thread is calling tasks, so I expcted each `task` to run on another thread as each `task` is actually a `std::packaged_task`. But then, let's say there were 100 such tasks, then I expect that the func, which each task is wrapping, should be called by 100 different threads, having 100 different thread ids. But it doesn't happen. The number of thread ids are never greater than the size of threadpool. That implies that these packaged tasks are getting called on the worker thread itself which I can't understand why/how?

Comment: It made a lot sense when you described `std::function` like that. Whenever I read about `std::function`, I always felt like every callable just decays into  `std::function`, just like an array decays into a pointer and looses its original identity. thank you!

Comment: `std::packaged_task` doesn't by itself create any threads. The actual function it wraps is executed on whichever thread calls `std::packaged_task::operator()`.

Comment: oh, this makes a lot of sense. thanks!